# How to connect 2 laptop located at different place

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, lan

I am trying to do a web based remote desktop application using Java Tomcat, what I know is that I need to configure the port forwarding on router, I am trying on WLAN, I can't ping another workstation connected to the same network. Is there any other way so that I can connect the remote laptop. How about if the laptop is located at another place, if said I have to right to configure the router.

Answer (score 0):

we have here two way for doing that!
if i understand you question you can use teamviewer and then you dont need any configs on your Gateway.
but if you want connect directly you must going to port forwarding in your router configuration web page and forward connection with some port to your labtop ip and remote desktop port

Comment: able to use Java code to do so? I found one is NAT Traversal. But don't quite understand how to plug into my code.

Comment: you can use http://jrdesktop.sourceforge.net/ ;)

Comment: or SkyFex is a free tool for secure access to remote computers. It's easy to use from the web.